# How to add functionality to my DataGrid Rows

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datagrid

I have dynamically created a DataGrid using database information. I want to make it so I am able to click on the rows that it has created and it calls another C# method which then loads more data.

I'm not entirely sure how to make the new method run different SQL queries, I'm guessing I am going to have to use the ID of the data that I have pulled from the database? But I dont know how to get that ID from the row either so it would be really helpful if you could help with that.

Here is the code that I have written to get the data and then create the DataGrid:

```
    protected void SubMenuLoadData(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView1.DataSource = GetData("SELECT [ID], [Description] FROM Table1 WHERE[Part Number] like 'A%'");
        DataGridView1.DataBind();
    }

    private DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ArrowEngineering"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type

Comment: If the row contains the necessary data get it in the CellClick event using e.RowIndex..

Comment: @TaW alright mate I have only just started using them so I have no idea what the difference is and I am using ImageClickEventArgs so I cant do that

Comment: `ImageClickEventArgs` sounds like ASP or WPF. - What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - But you wrote you want to drill deeper when the user clicks a row, right?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET Webforms and basically when I click a button it makes the datagrid appear. I then want to be able to click a row on the datagridview which loads even more data. I have to use ImageClickEventArgs dont I because I am using a asp:ImageButton

Comment: @TaW I forgot to tag you

Comment: See this article for a basic tutorial for working with GridView functionality. It should get you started: http://asp.net-informations.com/gridview/gridview-operations.htm